# Need to print CSV output into separate rows in Python, instead of one long string

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to print the output of a webscrape project into a CSV file.

So for example I have this list of supplier names under a list called SUPP_NAME: (just an example, the actual list has 50 items inside it)

```
['"FULIAN\\u0020\\u0028M\\u0029\\u0020SENDIRIAN\\u0020BERHAD"', '"RISO\\u0020SEKKEN\\u0020SDN.\\u0020BHD."', '"NATURE\\u0020PROFUSION\\u0020SDN.\\u0020BHD."']
```

and a list of numbers indicated years, under a list called SUPP_YEARS:

```
['"9"', '"4"', '"1"', '"1"']
```

My plan is to put them into a CSV, and then read them back in as a pandas dataframe, then perform decoding to get a bunch of values.

Code so far:

```
import csv

with open('output3.csv' , 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    headers = "Supplier_name,Years\n"

    f.write(headers)

    supp_names = re.findall(r'("supplierName"):("\w+.+")', results[17].text) 
    supp_years = re.findall(r'("supplierYear"):("\d+")', results[17].text)

    SUPP_NAME = []
    for title, name in supp_names:
        print (name)
        SUPP_NAME.append(name)
        #f.write(name + "\n")

    SUPP_YEAR = []    
    for year,number in supp_years:
        print (number)
        SUPP_YEAR.append(number)
        #f.write(number + "\n")

    writer.writerow([SUPP_NAME, SUPP_YEAR])
```

However, what I get is that under the `Supplier_name` and `Years` columns, one cell under each of these 2 columns is filled with a LONG list of items still contained in the list, instead of the items separated one by one.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: From what I see, this is normal behavior, you looped through to populate your list then write it all at once, what you probably want to do is iterate on both your lists while you write and only write the one on which you currently are, so you have 1 line per entry, also don't forget separators etc..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two `re.findall()` calls are giving you lists of items (hopefully both the same length). The idea is to then then extract an element from each and write this to your output file. Python has a useful function called [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) to do this. You give it both of your lists and the loop with give you an item from each on each iteration:

```
import csv

with open('output3.csv', 'w' newline='') as f_output:
    writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    writer.writerow(["Supplier_name" , "Years"])

    supp_names = re.findall(r'("supplierName"):("\w+.+")', results[17].text) 
    supp_years = re.findall(r'("supplierYear"):("\d+")', results[17].text)

    for name, year in zip(supp_names, supp_years):
        writer.writerow([name, year])
```

The `csv.writer()` object is designed to take a list of items and write them to your file with the desired (i.e. comma) delimiter automatically added between them.

I assume you are using Python 3.x? If not you should change the following:

```
with open('output3.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
```